# VoiceStates not updating discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a **command to move all the members in a voice channel** (the one the author of the command is in) **to another** (given in parameter).
But I have a problem, the **VoiceState won't update consistently**, connecting and changing channel is ok but if disconnect from the voice channel the bot will still see my voiceState as if I were connected.

```js
//The command file
const Discord= require('discord.js');
const {SlashCommandBuilder} = require("@discordjs/builders");
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('move')
        .setDescription('Move all the members to a specific voice channel')
        .addChannelOption(option =>
            option.setName('voicechannel')
                .setDescription('The voice channel to move everyone in')
                .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const author = interaction.member
        const voice = author.guild.voiceStates.cache
        console.log(voice.get(author.id))
        console.log(interaction.options.get('voicechannel').channel.id)
        if (voice.get(author.id) == undefined || voice.get(author.id) == null){
            await interaction.reply({content : 'You need to be in a voice channel first', ephemeral: true})
        } else if (interaction.options.get('voicechannel').channel.id == voice.get(author.id).channelId) {
            await  interaction.reply({content : 'Can\'t move to the same channel', ephemeral: true})
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({content : 'ok', ephemeral: true})
            ///TO IMPLEMENT CODE
        }
    },
};
```

```js
//my client constructor
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` [intent](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents) set upon Client construction.

```
const client: Client = new discord.Client({
    intents: 641,
});
```

I had a similar issue, where the state of the voice channels was set when the bot was started up, but would never update.

I used [this intents calculator](https://ziad87.net/intents/) to easily contain all the intents.

Check out the 'music bot' preset in particular (641).